# Change Font Awesome Icon on Click, but return to original icon when next item is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, onclick, font-awesome, toggleclass

I'm using Bootstrap 3 Panel's and have appended the Font Awesome Plus and Minus icons to the panel items. I'm looking for a way using Jquery to change the plus to a minus "onClick", then when another panel item is clicked **I want that minus icon to change back to plus**.

I have been experimenting with some Jquery and have come close.  I think I might just be missing something simple here. It seems to work fine for a few clicks, then it starts confusing which class to switch back to. My HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed faq-links" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Panel Title 1</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel body text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading13">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed faq-links" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse13" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse13"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Panel Title 2</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse13" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading13">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel body text 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed faq-links" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Panel Title 3</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
        <div class="panel-body">

    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Panel body text 3</p>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my Jquery looks like this:

```
//TOGGLE FONT AWESOME ON CLICK
 $('.faq-links').click(function(){
 $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o fa-2x fa-minus-square-o fa-2x')
 });
 $('.faq-links').blur(function(){
 $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o fa-2x fa-minus-square-o fa-2x')
 });
```

As you can see, I'm using click on one function, and blur on the next as the event listeners.  What am I doing wrong here? I have a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/t7jtnupu/)** set up to further explain my issue.

## Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update: Shivali Patel's answer that worked for me:**

```
$('.faq-links').click(function(){
var collapsed=$(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-plus-square-o');

$('.faq-links').find('i').removeClass('fa-minus-square-o');

$('.faq-links').find('i').addClass('fa-plus-square-o');
if(collapsed)
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o fa-2x fa-minus-square-o fa-2x')
});
```

He created a variable based on collapse and used addClass and removeClass in addition to the toggleClass events.  Great work Shivali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of `blur event`.
If you click outside of any accordion still blur event is called and changed the icons of relevant accordion. 

Example here :
 http://jsfiddle.net/t7jtnupu/2/

Comment: Shivali, thank you for your helpful answer. This solved my issue immediately. Many thanks!!!!